# How to connect to multiple Cassandra in different dc

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, spring-data-cassandra

I'm setting up an application in which i am using spark session to read data from Cassandra. I am able to read the data from Cassandra if i am passing one Cassandra node from a dc.
But how can i connect to 3 different Cassandra nodes which belong to 3 different dc in spark session.

Here the code which i am using:

spark session

```
spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkCassandraApp")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraContactPoints)
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", cassandraPort)
                .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", userName).config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", password)
                .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false").config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
                .master("local[4]").getOrCreate();
```

property file :

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=cassandra1ofdc1, cassandra2ofdc2, cassandra3ofdc3
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

when i try the above scenario i am getting the following exception:
Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Contact points contain multiple data centers: dc1, dc2, dc3
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need to use nodes from other DCs? New driver versions uses the same rule regarding selection of the local DC for all operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spark Cassandra Connector (SCC) allows to use only nodes from local data center, either defined by the `spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc` configuration parameter, or determined from the DC of the contact point(s) (that is performed by function `LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.determineDataCenter`).  SCC newer will use nodes from other DCs...

Comment: If this is the intended behavior, how can I utilize other datacenters with SCC?

Comment: What do you mean by utilize? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have two Cassandra datacenter and each has 4 nodes (each of these nodes work as a Spark worker as well)

From my Spark master, when I'm submitting a job, I expect all the nodes in my data centers to be used.

But if SCC can only work with the nodes in one Datacenter, what's going to happen to the nodes in other datacenters?